# 重複したIDの要素を結合する方法

Tags: python, r

```
ID_1 1
ID_2 3
ID_2 5
ID_2 1
ID_3 2
ID_3 3
…
```

---

```
ID_1 1
ID_2 1 3 5
ID_3 2 3
…
```

上記のような重複IDのあるデータセットから、重複のあったものを横結合するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？
重複したIDを1行にし、昇順で並べたいと思っています。
重複を削除する方法は多く見つかりますが、結合する方法は見つからずどう処理すればいいのか悩んでいます。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: R なら `aggregate` を使うと良いかと。 例えば、対象のデータフレームを df、 カラムを id と val とすると、`aggregate(val ~ id, data = df, function(x) { paste(sort(x), collapse = " ") })`

Answer (score 1):

Rの場合
tapplyで重複するIDごとのリストを作り、lapplyで好きな関数をあてれば、並び替えも簡単。

x <- tapply(c(1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3), c('ID_1', 'ID_2', 'ID_2', 'ID_2', 'ID_3', 'ID_3'), list)

lapply(x, sort)

Comment: tapply(c(1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3), c('ID_1', 'ID_2', 'ID_2', 'ID_2', 'ID_3', 'ID_3'), sort)
で一発だった。

Answer (score 0):

具体的なデータの形式が分からないので抽象的な話になりますが、例えばPythonでリストの辞書を使って次のように書くのはどうでしょうか。

```
data = [(1,1),(2,3),(2,5),(2,1),(3,2),(3,3)]

id_dict = {}

for d in data:
    id_dict.setdefault(d[0],[]).append(d[1])

for i, l in id_dict.items():
    print(i, " : ", sorted(l))
```

実行結果

```
1  :  [1]
2  :  [1, 3, 5]
3  :  [2, 3]
```

昇順で並べるのに`print`するところで整列しています。

IDの値の範囲が分からないので辞書を使っていますが、範囲が分かっていて（かつそれが小さいなら）リストのリストを使うことも考えられます。

Answer (score 0):

データ形式が指定されていないのですが、

**pandas**であれば、`groupby()` を使って簡単に記述できます。

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id':['ID_1','ID_2','ID_2','ID_2','ID_3','ID_3'],
    'value':[1,3,5,1,2,3]})

result = df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.groupby` を使った方法もあります。
`out` に並び順を保持するため `OrderedDict` を使ってますが並び順が不要であれば辞書でOKです。
`data` はキーになる項目でソートされている必要があります。

https://docs.python.jp/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>>
>>> data = [
...     ("ID_1", 1),
...     ("ID_2", 3),
...     ("ID_2", 5),
...     ("ID_2", 1),
...     ("ID_3", 2),
...     ("ID_3", 3),
... ]
>>> data
[('ID_1', 1), ('ID_2', 3), ('ID_2', 5), ('ID_2', 1), ('ID_3', 2), ('ID_3', 3)]
>>> out = OrderedDict()
>>> for k, g in groupby(data, key=lambda v: v[0]):
...     value = [v[1] for v in g]
...     out[k] = sorted(value)
...
>>> out
OrderedDict([('ID_1', [1]), ('ID_2', [1, 3, 5]), ('ID_3', [2, 3])])
>>> dict(out)
{'ID_1': [1], 'ID_2': [1, 3, 5], 'ID_3': [2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rでは`dplyr`, `tidyr`パッケージを使うのも良い方法だと思います．

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df = data.frame(
  id = c('ID_1', 'ID_2', 'ID_2', 'ID_2', 'ID_3', 'ID_3'),
  x  = c(1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3)
)

df_spread = df %>%
  arrange(id, x) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(no = row_number()) %>%
  spread(key = no, value = x, sep ='_')

print(df_spread)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>       id  no_1  no_2  no_3
#> * <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1   ID_1     1    NA    NA
#> 2   ID_2     1     3     5
#> 3   ID_3     2     3    NA
```